# PHP substr slow?

Tags: php, strings

If I have a long string:

```
// 10MB string
$string='';
for($run=0; $run<1000000; $run++)
$string.='012345689';
```

Then I perform many `substr`, cutting off small portions from the beginning.

```
for($run=0; $run<100000; $run++)
{
$temp=substr($string,0,10);
DoSomething($temp);
$string=substr($string,10);
}
```

It is VERY slow (20 seconds), which I tracked down to: `substr($string,10)` as the cause of the problem. Seems it is rebuilding the entire variable each time, which slowing the whole script down.

How can this be optimized, without incrementing the `start` offset of the first `substr` in the second code fragment?

EDIT: for those who are upset, the reason why I don't want to use an offset is because this would require keeping the entire string in memory the whole time. I'm trying to optimize both speed and memory.

Comment: Is the length of the substrings cut off at the beginning constant?

Comment: There is no reason not to keep track of offsets, simply do `$temp = substr( $string, $offset, 10 ); $offset += 10;`.... instead of `$string=substr($string,10);`

Comment: Can you use a list rather a single string?

Comment: Is this a real world use case - Doing 100000 operations on 1MB of data?

Comment: Yes, it is constant. I padded all the values out so that I wouldn't have to search.

Comment: Yes, a real world case, except it's probably 1,000,000 iterations on 100MB of data, about 1,000,000 times. Big project.

Comment: Are you able to `DoSomething()` as you read the string?

Comment: Yes, each little extracted string gets put into an array and used for various calculations. In the real script that is, the above is an example.

Comment: Why are you padding the strings and concatenating them into a big one, only to chunk them down and put them in an array? Is there a reason you cannot go straight to an array?

Comment: It's all compressed and saved into a file between the first and second code fragment. You don't need to tear apart my examples, they are only to illustrate how to duplicate the issue, the examples themselves are not the real world problem, which would be impossible to post here because it's too long.

Comment: I don't think you can free just *some* of the memory from the $string variable, thus you will have to rebuild the variable whenever you want to prune it.  It also seems to me that you're really trying to optimize for memory, and your first attempt created a performance problem...?  You mentioned the string is in a file, maybe just read part of the file (fseek) at a time and find the right balance of memory usage and file access overhead...

Comment: Your 10MB string is missing a million 7's.

Comment: General rule of thumb.  You can optimize for memory, or for speed. Optimizing for one is usually at the expense of the other.  There are exceptions to this of course but as a rule of thumb it tends to hold true most of the time.

Comment: Try [chunk_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) and [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
for($run=0; $run<100000; $run++)
{
$temp=substr($string,$run*10,10);
DoSomething($temp);
//$string=substr($string,10);
}
```

You trade RAM for performance: The original string will not become shorter, but you don't need the very expensive copying of the string again and again

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to cut the string without having to copy it over and over again. That sounds plausible to me. If it can't be done in PHP, then OK, this is the answer.

Comment: Small additional improvement: Rename $run to $offset and don't do $run++ but $offset += 10, so instead of increment and multiplication it only has to do an addition ... additionally saves a temporary variable (result of $run*10) ... while the effect will be hardly measurable relative to substr and DoSomething ;-)

Comment: How is it trading ram for performance? **Both**, RAM usage and performance are significantly better in the braindead obvious offset solution. I just tested it and `memory_get_peak_usage()` is 1.95 times higher than when using offset.

Comment: It's thinkable to create something which will chop the string without copy, but that's not what makes sense in PHP as it has some downsides like disabling coy-on-write. Also mind that choping stuff of would usually not result in memory actually returned to a usable pool unless the shorter string is copied to some other memory segment.

Comment: @Esailiaja, in theory the original solution has a higher peak memory usage (during the copy it needs 2x the space) but in average is lower (need smaller chunks lateron) ... in theory

Comment: @johannes True but that metric is pretty useless. You will have to allocate 10mb vs 20mb for your script, which one you want?

Comment: @Esalijia: Sorry for bein not precise enough: I ment a reasonable number of these scripts running parallell (which I consider a normal environment for PHP apps) will average lower in the original script.

Comment: Actually I don't care about PEAK memory usage at all. I can allocate any amount to the script. What I care about is the average memory usage of the running time of the script, since this will be run on multiple threads of multiple servers in parallel. It would save money on RAM if it uses less memory.

Comment: @EugenRieck Yeah but you need to allocate twice as much memory which means you can run 50% less scripts to make sure they work. The average use is only a bit higher, you can see that metric by using `memory_get_usage` but if you want to know how much you need to reserve for the script altogether, use `memory_get_peak_usage` which is about 2 times higher for using `substr` over offset. Let's say you have 200mb memory for use, then you can only run 10 scripts because at some point they could use 20mb each. But if your scripts only use max 10mb each, you can safely run 20 scripts at a time.

Comment: I don't know why you are arguing seeing as my QUESTION was if there were a way in which the string can be cut without copying it to another variable (which was causing the original problem), in which case there would not be twice the peak memory usage as the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can split string into array and then free memory by unsetting array elements when you don't need them anymore. Of cource PHP has big overhead for arrays, so you should split string into bigger parts then your read chunk size. Splitting a string by big chunks shouldn't be too slow. Example (badly tested, just a basic idea):

```
<?php
class ScumbagString {
    //Our main strings array
    private $string_array=array();

    //Basic settings
    private $chunk_size;
    private $array_element_size;

    //Array position variables
    private $insert_key;
    private $read_key;

    //Positions in array elements
    private $insert_element_space_left;
    private $read_offset;

    /**
     * 
     * @param Integer $chunk_size Size of a string you will read each time
     * @param Integer $chunks_concated Number of chunks in one array element
     * @param String $string String to add to internal array
    */
    public function __construct($chunk_size=10,$chunks_concated=1000,&$string='') {
        //Set default variables
        $this->insert_key=0;
        $this->read_key=0;

        $this->read_offset=0;

        $this->string_array[0]='';


        //Process passed variables
        $this->chunk_size=$chunk_size;
        $this->array_element_size=$chunk_size*$chunks_concated;
        $this->insert_element_space_left=$this->array_element_size;

        if($string) {
            $this->add($string);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a string to the end of internal array
     * @param String $string String to add
     */
    public function add(&$string) {
        $str_length_left=strlen($string);
        $offset=0;
        while($str_length_left) {
            $substr_len=min($this->insert_element_space_left,$str_length_left);

            $this->string_array[$this->insert_key].=substr($string,$offset,$substr_len);
            $offset+=$substr_len;
            $str_length_left-=$substr_len;
            if($substr_len===$this->insert_element_space_left) {
                $this->insert_key++;
                $this->string_array[$this->insert_key]='';

                $this->insert_element_space_left=$this->array_element_size;
            }
            else {
                $this->insert_element_space_left-=$substr_len;
            }
        }


    }

    /**
     * Get a chunk from internal array.
     * @return Mixed Either a string of $chunk_size from the begining of array or FALSE if fails.
     */
    public function get() {
        //This is a special case
        if($this->read_key===$this->insert_key) {
            //Check if we have enough data written to read
            if($this->read_offset+$this->chunk_size>$this->array_element_size-$this->insert_element_space_left) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        $return_str=substr($this->string_array[$this->read_key],$this->read_offset,$this->chunk_size);

        $this->read_offset+=$this->chunk_size;

        if($this->read_offset>=$this->array_element_size) {
            $this->read_offset=0;
            unset($this->string_array[$this->read_key]);
            $this->read_key+=1;
        }

        return $return_str;
    }
}
$sStr=new ScumbagString(10,5000);

$string='';
for($run=0; $run<1000000; $run++) {
    $string.='0123456789';
    //If it is possible - avoid using $string at all, just do 
    //$sStr->add('0123456789'); to lower peak memory usage
}

$sStr->add($string);

//Free string if you will not use it anymore
unset($string);

//In this cycle memory usage should slowly drop
//It will not drop by 10 each iteration, but it should drop
//by 10*5000 (+ array element overhead) each 5000's iteration.
for($run=0; $run<1000000; $run++)
{
    $temp=$sStr->get();
    DoSomething($temp);
}
```